# Exception: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to write very simple code to calculate the discount on a article. Following is the code and it throws the exception on the 3rd line in the code. The exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/basam/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/discounts.py", line 3, in <module>
    discount=0.1*price
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The code:

```
price=input('how much is your item?')
if int(price) <= 10:
    discount=0.1*price
```

Can someone advise on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Silvio Mayolo has stated, the problem is that your price variable is of type String. You can wrap your input() call to cast the input value to an integer which should allow for the calculation to work

```
price = int(input('how much is your item?'))
if price <= 10:
    discount = 0.1 * price

print(discount)
>> 0.5
```

or better yet - considering you're dealing with 'money' which can have decimal values, use a 'float' type rather than 'int'

```
price = float(input("how much is item 2?"))
if price <= 10:
    discount = 0.1 * price

print(discount)
>> 0.5
```

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. You can multiply an int by a float just fine. The problem is that `price` is a string, not anything numerical

Answer (score 5):

The key is `int(price)`. The `input` command returns a string which is stored in the variable `price`.

In the second line, `price` is converted to a number by the call `int(price)`, but that result is not stored anywhere. It is used for the comparison and then discarded. So when you go to multiply in the third line, you're trying to multiply a number times a string.

Answer (score -1):

Change to 
`discount=0.1*float(price)`